# Websocket Poco can't receive big data

Tags: c++, websocket, poco-libraries

I downloaded and built Poco project from Poco and run WebsocketServer project in poco-1.7.6\Net\samples\WebSocketServer.

When I worked with small data that is smaller 128 KB (131072 bytes), it work perfectly. But if I work with bigger data (I need to send 20 MB),  my data will be cut so server don't receive data enough.

Here is code that I copy in project:

```
        WebSocket ws(request, response);
        char *buffer = new char[1000000]; // It just receive 131072 bytes
        int flags;
        int n;
        do
        {
            n = ws.receiveFrame(buffer, sizeof(buffer), flags);
            ws.sendFrame(buffer, tmp.length(), flags);
        } while (n > 0 || (flags & WebSocket::FRAME_OP_BITMASK) != WebSocket::FRAME_OP_CLOSE);
        delete[] buffer;
```

Deframe code:

```
int WebSocketImpl::receiveBytes(void* buffer, int length, int)
{
    char header[MAX_HEADER_LENGTH];
    int n = receiveNBytes(header, 2);
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        _frameFlags = 0;
        return n;
    }
    poco_assert (n == 2);
    Poco::UInt8 lengthByte = static_cast<Poco::UInt8>(header[1]);
    int maskOffset = 0;
    if (lengthByte & FRAME_FLAG_MASK) maskOffset += 4;
    lengthByte &= 0x7f;
    if (lengthByte > 0 || maskOffset > 0)
    {
        if (lengthByte + 2 + maskOffset < MAX_HEADER_LENGTH)
        {
            n = receiveNBytes(header + 2, lengthByte + maskOffset);
        }
        else
        {
            n = receiveNBytes(header + 2, MAX_HEADER_LENGTH - 2);
        }
        if (n <= 0) throw WebSocketException("Incomplete header received", WebSocket::WS_ERR_INCOMPLETE_FRAME);
        n += 2;
    }
    Poco::MemoryInputStream istr(header, n);
    Poco::BinaryReader reader(istr, Poco::BinaryReader::NETWORK_BYTE_ORDER);
    Poco::UInt8 flags;
    char mask[4];
    reader >> flags >> lengthByte;
    _frameFlags = flags;
    int payloadLength = 0;
    int payloadOffset = 2;
    if ((lengthByte & 0x7f) == 127)
    {
        Poco::UInt64 l;
        reader >> l;
        if (l > length) throw WebSocketException(Poco::format("Insufficient buffer for payload size %Lu", l), WebSocket::WS_ERR_PAYLOAD_TOO_BIG);
        payloadLength = static_cast<int>(l);
        payloadOffset += 8;
    }
    else if ((lengthByte & 0x7f) == 126)
    {
        Poco::UInt16 l;
        //lenBuffer = l;

        if (l > length) throw WebSocketException(Poco::format("Insufficient buffer for payload size %hu", l), WebSocket::WS_ERR_PAYLOAD_TOO_BIG);
        payloadLength = static_cast<int>(l);
        payloadOffset += 2;
    }
    else
    {
        Poco::UInt8 l = lengthByte & 0x7f;

        if (l > length) throw WebSocketException(Poco::format("Insufficient buffer for payload size %u", unsigned(l)), WebSocket::WS_ERR_PAYLOAD_TOO_BIG);
        payloadLength = static_cast<int>(l);
    }

    if (lengthByte & FRAME_FLAG_MASK)
    {
        reader.readRaw(mask, 4);
        payloadOffset += 4;
    }

    int received = 0;

    if (payloadOffset < n)
    {
        std::memcpy(buffer, header + payloadOffset, n - payloadOffset);
        received = n - payloadOffset;
    }

    if (received < payloadLength)
    {
        n = receiveNBytes(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer) + received, payloadLength - received);
        if (n <= 0) throw WebSocketException("Incomplete frame received", WebSocket::WS_ERR_INCOMPLETE_FRAME);
        received += n;
    }

    if (lengthByte & FRAME_FLAG_MASK)
    {
        char* p = reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < received; i++)
        {
            p[i] ^= mask[i % 4];
        }
    }
    return received;
}
```

Can anyone help me, please!

P/s: Sorry about my English

**UPDATE:** I just got this problem in Chrome. It work fine with Firefox and Edge

Answer (score 0):

Setting [setChunkedTransferEncoding](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPMessage.html#21281) should make it work.

In the code before the response is sent set:
`response.setChunkedTransferEncoding(true);`

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work, this problem is about receiving data, I replaced statement with request. Tks you @@

Comment: Yes, I know that this is about receiving data. You need to set response to be chunked (not request) so that you can receive big data in chunks.

Comment: I set response too, but nothing changed, Tks you

Comment: Try also setting `setContentLength()` to response string size.

Comment: This is all I remember, sorry - it was few years ago when I was facing similar problem. You may want to debug Poco source code to find a solution.

Comment: OMG, I just got this problem with Chrome. When I test with Firefox and Edge it work perfect. This thing can help you get any idea?